# Calculate AUC of a stream dataframe of points in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, auc

I'm trying to calculate the AUC of a series of points. The problem is that my  dataframe of points gets updated every seconds with a new point, and I get a new frame of last 60 points on my dataframe.

Is there an easy way to keep track of AUC, considering that each second I lose the AUC of the oldest point when a new point arrives?

Is there any way to apply np.trapz to a whole dataframe? Or Like df.trapz().rolling....

Thank you

Comment: Just an idea, not statistically evaluated idea.  If the number of points per min are roughly the same, would it be ok to have a rolling average of the AUC ?  You can calculate the AUC per min and then do a rolling average for the past hour, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think this will work for my project, because actually I need to calculate the gradient of the gradient of AUC in order to find AUD variations. If I do the average it will decrease the precision.